# ASP.NET MVC View/Site Design

Tags: asp.net-mvc, css

This stems from my question that i started at [MVC Beginner Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561898/mvc-beginner-question)

Im now confident in developing a MVC website from the MVC side of things.

My fatal floor now is the UI level designing. i.e. designing views and master pages including css styling.

Just wanting to get any advice on where i should start? Im currently about to look at the expression studio to see if that will help.

I need to get up and running in this quickly so that it doesnt hold back the development of the website.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Its almost impossible to answer "how should I learn" questions.  Too many variables, what you already know and how you learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look at a CSS grid-framework like [960 Grid System](http://960.gs/) or [Blueprint](http://www.blueprintcss.org/).

There is often controversy from CSS/Markup purists as to whether the use of such frameworks is valid, but they often overlook that not *everyone* is a CSS expert. I have found that the use of these frameworks has saved me hours of productivity since my CSS skills (as a programmer) are not that great.

As far as using Expression, I tend to use this as a "test-bed" with simple HTML files. The Designer and CSS Style support seem to be more interactive than that which Visual Studio supports, so for quick mock-ups -- Expression, then move that HTML/CSS over to VS as soon as possible.

One other priceless tool to use while designing is the add-on "[Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)" for Firefox ... it allows you to inspect single elements on your page, the CSS properties affecting that element - it even allows you to change CSS attributes "on-the-fly" to immediately see the ramificatiions. This tool has saved me HOURS!

Comment: No No No No No.  You'll never learn CSS/HTML/UI if you start with a framework.  Learn the basics first then give the frameworks a try.

Answer (score 0):

Consider finding a suitable theme in a free open source template.

Consider something that suits at http://www.freecsstemplates.org/.